# как получить html строку java

Tags: java, android, html

я отправляю html строку, а затем мне нужно получить, то что должно получиться после отправления html, как такое сделать ?

запрос:

```
 HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(new HttpGet("http://sity.com");
```

Comment: поясните, что значит "я отправляю html строку"? куда вы ее отправляете?

Comment: запросом, пример запроса добавил в вопрос.

Comment: как вы делаете этот запрос?

Comment: Не стоит полностью менять содержимое вопроса, т.к. это делает ответы бессмысленными. Вместо этого лучше задайте новый вопрос.

Answer (score 3):

Вы отправляете не HTML строку, а HTTP запрос и в ответ получаете HTTP ответ. Получить содержимое ответа в вашем случае можно вот так

```
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(new HttpGet("http://sity.com"));
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
String responseString = EntityUtils.toString(entity, "UTF-8");
```

Если не будет ошибок, то в `responseString` будет HTML строка

Comment: Вы правы на счёт hppt запроса, я не так сказал в вопросе. И в вопросе про получение я тоже ошибся. Знаете как можно получить, URL строку после выполнения запроса?

Comment: поясните, что значит " как можно получить, URL строку после выполнения запроса"? у вас в запросе уже есть URL: `http://sity.com`

Comment: после того как URL (http://sity.com) выполнится, появится другой (http://sity.com/parametr1) и вот этот другой нудно мне получить

Comment: @ИгорьКондауров URL не выполняется - выполняется запрос. Когда я открываю в браузере sity.com у меня URL не меняется. Что вы делаете, что бы он поменялся? Я ответил на ваш вопрос? Если да, то пометьте ответ как принятый. Если иначе, то исправьте вопрос.